# ZF2 / Doctrine Form Multi-select Element for Many-to-Many Relation

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

If I have 2 entities related as "many-to-many", it's quite easy to draw a multi-select element in the form (for example Product <- many-to-many -> Category):

ProductFieldset:

```
    $this->add(array(
        'type' => 'DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectSelect',
        'name' => 'category',
        'attributes' => array(
            'multiple' => 'multiple',
        ),
        'options' => array(
            'target_class' => 'Application\Entity\Category',
            'property' => 'name',
            'label' => 'Select categories',
            'find_method' => array(
                'name' => 'findAll',
            ),
        ),
    ));
```

But how can I implement the multi-select box if these entities are linked with help of third object? (Product <- many-to-one -> ProductCategory <- one-to-many -> Category).

Usually I use Form Collections for that (http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.form.collections.html) but sometimes it'd be more convenient to use simple multi-select element wrapped by some jQuery plugin.

Comment: Is ProductCategory just a join table? If so, if you've written it correctly in your model definition, Doctrine should be able to handle that natively - in fact, for a many to many relationship, this is how doctrine would do it in the database, usually?

Comment: `ProductCategory` is an entity that links 2 another entities. `Product` entity only knows about `ProductCategory` entity but not about `Category`. So I don't see how Doctrine can handle that. Could you please write an example of code?

Comment: Is ```ProductCategory```'s only job to link the two tables? If so, then this is just defined in the product model: ```ManyToMany(targetEntity="Category")``` and Doctrine will create the join table if it is needed and automatically abstract any usage quirks as you define here. If this isn't what you mean, then your DB may not be normalised and you may think about restructuring. Also see: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html and http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html

Comment: No, `ProductCategory` entity also contains additional fields. Here's a quote from the Doctrine documentation you provided link to: "Why are many-to-many associations less common? Because frequently you want to associate additional attributes with an association, in which case you introduce an association class. Consequently, the direct many-to-many association disappears and is replaced by one-to-many/many-to-one associations between the 3 participating classes."